# Strange behavior with stack not popping correctly

Tags: c, stack

I'm trying to refresh my memory of C. I have a simple program that checks HTML tags in a text file to make sure that they all match up with each other. I use a stack for this. Here's the code in question:

```
char *tag, *endTag;
stackADT stack = newStack();
while (!feof(input))
{
    tag = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    tag = getNextTag(input, &line);
    printf("tag is %s\n", tag);     
    if (*(tag + 1) != '/') //if it is not a closing tag
    {
        push(stack, tag);
        printf("%s was pushed\n", tag);
    }
    else
    {
        endTag = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
        endTag = pop(stack);
        printf("%s was popped\n", endTag);
        check = doTagsMatch(endTag, tag);
        if (check == 0)
        {
            printf("Error at line %d: %s and %s do not match.\n", line, endTag, tag);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    free(tag);
}
```

From a simple file with html, body, and p tags, the output is this:

```
tag is <html>
<html> was pushed
tag is <body>
<body> was pushed
tag is <p>
<p> was pushed
tag is </p>
 was popped
Error at line 1:  and </p> do not match.
```

I know the stack itself works correctly, because I did a separate SSCCE with several ints and it worked fine. That is the only place in the program that I use endTag, so I can't figure out why it's not getting anything from pop. The only thing I can think of is that it's somehow a pointer issue (my stack elements are void*, if it matters).

Comment: `tag = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));` - why the cast? Why the `malloc()` at all?

Comment: Your problem seems to be in the stack class, so you should post that code. Besides you seem to create a memory leak there.

Comment: You dont need malloc().
if (*(tag + 1) != '/')what are you trying to do here? this is wrong.

Comment: I suspect that you're reusing buffers/pointers so the data you 'push' on the stack get overwritten. The fact that you `malloc()` memory that's never used (and is immediately leaked)  indicates a problem with understanding pointers. But we'd need to see more of your program to do more than guess at what the problem is.

Comment: SO seems to not want to work with me on code tags. I've put it on pastebin until I can get it working.

As for the mallocs, as I said, I'm jogging my memory here. I'm okay with leaks that don't shut down my program, because I can always go back and review those subjects and fix them up.

http://pastebin.com/raenAWSb

Comment: @DanielWard: don't try to use code tags, just indent your code by four space, or select the code lines and click the "{}" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration, you assign `tag` from `getNextTag` and later call `free(tag)`. Once you free `tag`, the contents of the memory it points to are no longer valid (the C standard does not define the behavior if you try to use them).

You have not shown us the definition of `push`, but I suspect it merely records the value it is passed (`tag`) and does not make a copy of what `tag` points to. Thus, when you call `pop`, it returns the value `tag` had when the opening tag was pushed, but that value is a pointer to memory that is no longer valid.

Either `push` must make a copy of the string it is passed or `free(tag)` must not be called until after the value is popped from the stack and is no longer needed. (E.g., at the end of the `else` clause that pops the tag, call both `free(endTag)` and `free(tag)`. Do not call `free(tag)` at the end of the `while` loop.)

Additionally, these sequences are pointless and leak memory:

```
tag = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
tag = getNextTag(input, &line);

endTag = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
endTag = pop(stack);
```

In each case, `tag` or `endTag` is assigned a value returned from `malloc`, but that value is immediately overwritten by another assignment. This means the value returned by `malloc` is lost, and the memory remains allocated but never used. In each case, you should delete the line containing the `malloc`.

Comment: It looks like it was simply a matter of me misusing `malloc` and `free`. I removed the two `malloc`s in the loop and placed the `free` outside of the while loop, and everything works fine now. I guess I remember less than I thought I did. Thanks to everyone who pointed this out.

Comment: If you put the free outside the loop you still leak memory. You must malloc, push, pop, free in that sequence, because they are related to each other. Not malloc outside the if clause, because it belongs to the push, just like free should be inside the clause for pop.

Answer (score 0):

These lines are suspect

```
tag = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
tag = getNextTag(input, &line);
```

Since you overwrite the pointer you have just received as result from malloc. Then, you allocate just 1 char, which is also probabily wrong.

Similar pattern is replicated later for endTag.

Maybe the malloc should be done by getNextTag (or you should give the malloc-ed area to the function as argument), and it must be no less than the length of the tag (plus 1 for the string terminator), e.g. `sizeof(char) * (length+1)` (`sizeof(char) == 1` so you can omit it).

Then you do free `tag` (wrongly, since you are not freeing what you allocated), but not endTag...